# Where vs orderyBydescending query link

Tags: c#

I try to query like this below

```
ViewBag.TopLikes = blog.OrderByDescending(a => a.TotalVote);
```

and another i use this

```
ViewBag.TopLikes = blog.Where(a => a.TotalVote >= 1).OrderByDescending(a => a.TotalVote);
```

So the first without where and the second still query using where.
So which one is the best for speed the first or the second Thanks

Comment: Both will give completely different output. First one will give results including the blogs who have 0 number of votes and second one will just filter them out. And as for the speed in second one you are running one more method call to filter out the data so it will be slow than the first.

Comment: You should try it yourself depending on the content and structure of your database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first is more efficient simply because you're performing one extra operation in the second example with `Where(a => a.TotalVote >= 1)` and surely we can agree that performing something is more work than not doing it...

Nonetheless, it's important to note that you're performing two *different* things which requires *different* operations so it might not even make much sense to compare them performance wise.

- The first sorts everything descending regardless of the `TotalVote` so **all** the objects will be in the result.
- The second retains only the objects where they have at least 1 `TotalVote` and then sorts then descending so as a result the objects where the `TotalVote` is not at least 1 is not included in the result.